# Related Rates-Ships Probelm

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> A sailboat 4 miles west of Port Stanza sails toward Port Stanza at 5 miles per hour. At the same moment, a motorboat 3 miles north of Port Stanza travels due south, toward Port Stanza, at 2 miles per hour.

I set up a traingle with the origin being Port Stanza, and set the first sail boat 4 units to the left of the origin, and the other sail boat 3 units above the origin.

Which leads to my questions

$$\frac{a(\frac{da}{dt})+b(\frac{db}{dt})}{c}=\frac{dc}{dt}$$
Should $a$, and $\frac{db}{dt}$ here be substituted as a negative number, since $a$ is west of the origin, and $\frac{db}{dt}$ since the second sail boat is going south to the origin?

$$a=4mi$$
$$\frac{da}{dt}=5\frac{mi}{h}$$
$$b=3mi$$
$$\frac{db}{dt}=2\frac{mi}{h}$$
$$c=5mi$$
The answer I got with it all being plugged in postive is $\frac{26}{5}\frac{mi}{h}$

Comment: What are $a,b,c$? And what are you trying to solve for?

Comment: $a,b,c$ are $4,3,5$ respectively.

Comment: What does $\frac{da}{dt}$ represent then? This doesn't make any sense and I still don't know what you're asking. Try revising your question.

Comment: If $a,b,c$ are what they should be, the choice of signs is correct. Note that $a,b,c$ are varying. Presumably you were asked to find how fast is the distance between them changing at a certain instant. What instant?  Part of the question is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the sailboat is at $a$ and the motor-boat is at $b$.

you are using $c$ for distance.

$c =  \sqrt {a^2 + b^2}\\
\frac {dc}{dt} = \frac {a \frac {da}{dt} + b\frac{db}{dt}}{c}$

$a<0$ (to the left of the origin) and $\frac {da}{dt} > 0$ (headed toward the origin)

$b>0$ (above of the origin) and $\frac {db}{dt} < 0$ (headed toward the origin).

$\frac {dc}{dt} < 0$ since the boats are getting closer together $c$ is getting smaller. (and both terms in the numerator are $<0$ while the denominator is strictly positive)

Answer (score 1):

Let $a(t) = 4 - 5t$ be the distance of the sailboat from the port, as a function of time, and let $b(t) = 3 - 2t$ be the distance of the motorboat from the port. Then the distance between the two boats is $c(t) = \sqrt{a(t)^2 + b(t)^2}$.

Comment: So $a$, and $\frac{db}{dt}$ be substituted as negative numbers?